# How to trust a specific certificate while sending request using Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl-certificate, retrofit

I am sending all my request using Retrofit.Currently I have code for trusting all certificates. But now I want to trust a specific certificate for sending all Api request.How to trust a specific certificate while sending request using Retrofit. Also I want to know in which format I need to add the certificate in source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
CertificatePinner certPinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("your domain",
          "sha256/certificate_public_key")
    .build();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(certPinner)
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("your base url")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();
```

Comment: what is sha256?

Comment: Fingerprint of your certificate.

Comment: openssl x509 -in path/your_certificate.cer -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

Comment: Is there any other way other than certificate pinning

Comment: You can look [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config). 
There are all here.